# Facebook Page Embed Make Responsive - Previous Post Solutions Not Working

Tags: javascript, facebook, iframe

--UPDATE--
Here is my solution to the issue. It was curious that I was unable to use javascript variables for the width and height in the facebook plugin to generate a perfect fit everytime. I simply have set the height and width of the plugin to very high values which make it fit, surprisingly without a crop. I have a delay function that fires after resize to reload the plugin. The only downside with this method is the scrollbar can seem a bit funny because the height and width of the plugin is set so high.

```
<div id="facebookFeed">
        <div class="fb-page" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/correlationone/" data-tabs="timeline" data-small-header="true" data-width="2000" data-height="1000" data-hide-cover="true" data-show-facepile="false">
            <div class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore">
                <blockquote cite="https://www.facebook.com/correlationone/">
                    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/correlationone/">Correlation One</a>
                </blockquote>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var feed = document.getElementById("facebookFeed");

    function reloadFeed(){
        for (var i = feed.childNodes.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            feed.removeChild(feed.childNodes[i]).remove();
        }

        feed.innerHTML = `<div class="fb-page" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/correlationone/" data-tabs="timeline" data-small-header="true" data-width="2000" data-height="1000" data-hide-cover="true" data-show-facepile="false">
                <div class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore">
                    <blockquote cite="https://www.facebook.com/correlationone/">
                        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/correlationone/">Correlation One</a>
                    </blockquote>
                </div>
            </div>`

        FB.XFBML.parse();
    }

    var delay = (function(){
      var timer = 0;
      return function(callback, ms){
        clearTimeout (timer);
        timer = setTimeout(callback, ms);
      };
    })();

    $(window).resize(function() {
        delay(function(){
          reloadFeed();
        }, 500);
    });

    </script>
```

--Original Post Below--

I am trying to make a facebook page embed responsive. I have tried this every damn which way and I don't understand why this is not working.The page is being loading as a wordpress page template.

The main approach I am using now is to add the plugin after page load to get the size of the height and width dynamically, then add it to the document and parse. Unfortunately nothing appears on parse. I check the DOM in console and the element is there.

```
<body>

    <?php include('templates/analytics.html');?>
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>(function(d, s, id) {
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
      js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
      js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.6&appId=547400675437424";
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

    <div id='fullpage'>

    <?php include('templates/nav.html');?>

    <div id="facebookFeed">

    </div>

    </div>


    <?php get_footer(); ?>

    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        var height = window.innerHeight,
            width = window.innerWidth,
            feedHeight = height * 0.912,
            feedWidth = height * 0.3,
            feed = document.getElementById("facebookFeed");

        feed.innerHTML = `<div class="fb-page" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/correlationone/" data-tabs="timeline" data-small-header="true" data-adapt-container-width="true" data-width=${feedWidth} data-height=${feedHeight} data-hide-cover="true" data-show-facepile="false">
                <div class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore">
                    <blockquote cite="https://www.facebook.com/correlationone/">
                        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/correlationone/">Correlation One</a>
                    </blockquote>
                </div>
            </div>`

        FB.XFBML.parse();
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin#resizing – simply not possible; the plugin will only adapt its width to the container element on initialization, it doesn’t react to any changes later on.

Comment: I am aware I have to rerender the plugin on resize. Hence my FB.XFBML.parse();

Comment: You are calling that method only once in the `fbAsyncInit` event – and I am not sure if that event does even fire, when you embed the SDK with the parameters embedded in the hash part of it’s URL. Plus, once an element is parsed and transformed into a plugin, it won’t be parsed again – so you’d need to remove it, replace it with a new one, and then parse again. (Or at least you would have to remove the indicators that tells the method that an element has been parsed already.)

Comment: Hey CBroe I've read your comments and updated the original post. I am adding in the plugin html afterwards and calling the parse but the plugin fails to render.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, I want a big (width:500px) embedd on desktop and a small (width:350px) embedd on mobile. I have the solution, this is what i used:

The javascript:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
function autoResizeManual(id, newwidth, newheight ){

    document.getElementById(id).width = (newwidth) + "px";
    document.getElementById(id).height = (newheight) + "px";

}
//-->
</script>
```

Then the PHP - there are two cases - for regular posts the default width from FB is 500px, for video it's 560px.

```
 if($deviceType != 'computer') { //check if it's a mobile any way you want
    if(stripos($my_embed,"<iframe") !== false) { 
//check if the fb frame is prezent in the embed

            if(stripos($my_embed,"&width=500") !== false) {
//if it's a regular post
                $embed_width = '320';
                $embed_height = '500';
                $my_embed = str_ireplace('&width=500', '&width=320', $my_embed);
            }

if(stripos($my_embed,"&width=560") !== false) {

//if it's a video
                $embed_width = '320';
                $embed_height = '200';
                $my_embed = str_ireplace('&width=560', '&width=320', $my_embed);
            }

                $change_petition = '<iframe id="iframe1" onLoad="autoResizeManual(\'iframe1\',\''.$embed_width.'\',\''.$embed_height.'\');" ';

//code to be injected to launch the javascript

                $my_embed=  str_ireplace('<iframe', $change_petition, $my_embed);

//the injection

    }
    }

print $my_embed
```

Comment: Interesting to see your solution. I will update the main psot with how I got mine to work. I was unable to set the height and width of the plugin with javascript as variables which was surprising for me. I found that for whatever reason just setting a very high width or height on the plugin made it fit appropriately. I also have a delay on my resize function for when it has finished.